# Wordpress Genesis, if on a blog post

Tags: wordpress, if-statement, genesis

I am trying to add conditional logic to blog posts, but I cannot work out how to do that.
Both

```
if ( is_singular( 'post' ) ) {
```

and

```
if ( is_single() ) {
```

return false

Comment: hmm both should work fine. Where are you placing them? Can you include more info where and how.

Comment: @Bjorn - I have
`if ( is_singular( 'post' ) ) {
} else {
 echo 'no'; 
}`
at the bottom of functions.php

Comment: i've added a test function for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after reading your comment i know why it isn't working. You cannot use it directly in functions.php.

**Why**
functions.php runs way before the `is_single()` method is available.

**How to use it**

- Use it in functions that are loaded by hooks, more info about WP
  action hooks [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference).
- You can also use it directly in page templates. I.e. `single.php` etc.

**Example**
You can place this directly in your functions.php

```
add_action('wp','testing_is_single_method');
function testing_is_single_method() {
  if(is_single()) {
    add_action('wp_footer', function() {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">alert('HEY THIS IS A SINGLE (BLOG) POST');</script>
    <?php
    });
  }
}
```

Regards, Bjorn

Comment: Thanks, I've never known this, maybe I've just never tried it